# Summernote change height value after initial setup

Tags: javascript, summernote

I have summernote working on my website, as intended, with:

```
    $('#summernote').summernote({
        height: $(document).height() - ($("#Maintable").height() + $("#TblTop").height() + 60),
        minHeight: null,             // set minimum height of editor
        maxHeight: null,             // set maximum height of editor
        focus: true,

        toolbar: [
            // [groupName, [list of button]]
            ['style', ['fontname', 'bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
            ['font', ['strikethrough', 'superscript', 'subscript']],
            ['fontsize', ['fontsize', 'undo', 'redo']],
            ['color', ['color']],
            ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
            ['height', ['height']],
            ['insert', ['picture', 'video', 'table']],
            ['search', ['findnreplace', 'changecolor']]
        ],
        buttons: {
            changecolor: ChangeColorButton
        }
    });
```

However, when I call the following code in a function that gets called on `window.onresize`, in order to change the height value, nothing happens. What should I do?

```
   $('#summernote').summernote({
                height: 100     
   });
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://summernote.org/getting-started/#basic-api), it seems that **summernote** does not provide api to set the height after initialization.

However, by inspecting the html structure of the created editor, the `height`, `minHeight` and `maxHeight` options are applied to a `div` with `class="note-editable"`. So we set the height of this `div` instead. Following code snippet show how to change the height of the editor after initialize.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var t = $('#summernote').summernote(
  {
  height: 100,
  focus: true
}
  );
  $("#btn").click(function(){
    $('div.note-editable').height(150);
  });
});
```

```html
<!-- include libraries(jQuery, bootstrap) -->
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script> 
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.js"></script> 

<!-- include summernote css/js -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.9/summernote.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.9/summernote.js"></script>
<div id="summernote">Original height is 100. Click the button to change the height to 150</div>
<button id="btn">Change Height</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

It can be done with JS only, but its a nasty workaround:

```js
let summernoteOptions = {
        height: 300
    }

$('#summernote').summernote(summernoteOptions);

$(document).on('click', '#change', function(){

summernoteOptions.height = 100;

  let content = $('#summernote').summernote('code');

  $('#summernote').summernote('destroy');
  $('#summernote').summernote(summernoteOptions);
  $('#summernote').summernote('code', content);

});
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script> 
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.js"></script> 

<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.9/summernote.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.9/summernote.js"></script>
<div id="summernote">Some text...</div>
<button id="change">Change Height Button</button>
```

Comment: This worked really well. I added a button to toggle between scroll mode and full-screen and this was the perfect way to implement it. Thank you!